# Facebook login returning an empty Access Token

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-login, facebook-access-token, facebook-unity-sdk

*Unity 4.3.3f1*

*SDK Version 5.0.4*

*Build Version 140220.cc3a9c089a2eb9e*

---

Hello, I've been developing a game for the past 4 months using the Facebook SDK for Unity and I've been experiencing an issue since last friday. Everytime I try to log in into my application from my app, the Result.Text from the method LoginCallback(FBResult result){} returns the following string:

```
{"is_logged_in":false,"user_id":"","access_token":"","access_token_expires_at":"01/01/0001 00:00:00"}
```

So, for some reason it's not getting the user_id nor is generating the correct token to use on the application.

I made sure that my Package Name, Class Name and Key Hashes match between my facebook settings on the Unity SDK andmy App Settings on Facebook, they do.

One thing I noticed that could mean something or not, I don't know is that the Class name is now

```
com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity
```

on my FacebookSettings from Unity so I changed it to the same value on the my App Setting from Facebook.

I pushed the Regenerate Android Manifest button and this is my manifest in case it helps identify the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.unity3d.player" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityPlayerActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="\ 1422526867979289" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity" android:exported="true">
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

PS: Also, one quick question. Which is the manifest that works? The one located on:

```
Assets/Android/AndroidManifest.xml
```

or the one on:

```
Assets/Plugins/Android/AndroidManifest.xml
```

Nevertheless, both Manifests are exactly the same as the one I posted here. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for using our sdk! What is the set of permissions you are requiring during login? We found a bug with requiring only "publish_actions" permission. Also, do you use any other plugins? Correct android manifest should be taken from Assets/Plugins/Android. What else is in your Assets/Android folder? Your android manifest should look like this http://pastebin.mozilla.org/4704196 So move intent filters to "com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" and get rid of com.facebook.unity.FBUnityPlayerActivity.

Comment: Hi @juraj I just answered the question, the problem was within the ksytore. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a fellow developer suggested, the problem was in fact that the Facebook Login stopped working when I added the Keystore to be able to upload my apk to the playstore. Whit the keystore added, I needed to process it with keytool and upload to my Facebook App Acount the newly created Keyhash.

For future reference, it would be good that whenever something like this happens the sdk can throw an exception or something instead of an empty array, it would be much simpler to try and solve the problem.

Comment: You should use logcat when developing for android. Easiest way is to install Eclipse, go to Window->Show view->Other expand Android and select Logcat. Then setup filters for your application package and tags "Unity", "FBUnitySDK" and "fb4a". This way you can really see whats going on. In your case you would see "Invalid application {SOME APP ID}" under fb4a tag.

Comment: Thank you very much @juraj , I always use Logcat when working with Unity and always with the "Unity" filter. I didn't know about fb4a so I'll keep that in mind. Thanks!